# Thrust: why always host code is executed in spite of __CUDA_ARCH__

Tags: cuda, thrust

I try to define two branches in code: one for CUDA execution and the other - without it (with future OMP in mind). But when I use macro `__CUDA_ARCH__` it looks as if always the host code is executed. But I supposed that Thrust by default use CUDA (and branch for device code). What's wrong with my code?
Here it is:

```
#include <thrust/transform.h>                                 
#include <thrust/functional.h>                                
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>                
#include <stdio.h>                                            

struct my_op                                                  
{                                                             
    my_op(int init_const) : constanta(init_const) {}      
    __host__ __device__ int operator()(const int &x) const
    {                                                     
        #if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__)                    
            return 2 * x * constanta;    // never executed - why?
        #else                                     
            return x * constanta;        // always executed                 
        #endif                       
    }                                                     

private:                                                      
    int constanta;                                        
};                                                            

int main()                                                    
{                                                             
 int data[7] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };                        
 thrust::counting_iterator<int> first(10);                     
 thrust::counting_iterator<int> last = first + 7;              

 int init_value = 1;                                           
 my_op op(init_value);                                         

 thrust::transform(first, last, data, op);                     
 for each (int el in data)                                     
    std::cout << el << " ";                               

 std::cout << std::endl;                                       
}
```

I expect that "transform" will define vector as multiplied by 2*constanta but I see that host code is used - the output is "10 11 12 13 14 15 16", not "20 22 24 26 28 30 32" (as expected).

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thrust is choosing the host path because one of your data items supplied to the thrust transform operation is in host memory:

```
 thrust::transform(first, last, data, op); 
                                ^^^^
```

If you want a thrust algorithm to operate on the device, generally speaking all the *container* data you pass to/from must also reside in device memory.

Here's a modification to your code that demonstrates that thrust will follow the device path if we replace `data` with a device-resident container:

```
$ cat t13.cu
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct my_op
{
    my_op(int init_const) : constanta(init_const) {}
    __host__ __device__ int operator()(const int &x) const
    {
        #if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__)
            return 2 * x * constanta;    // never executed - why?
        #else
            return x * constanta;        // always executed
        #endif
    }

private:
    int constanta;
};

int main()
{
// int data[7] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
 thrust::counting_iterator<int> first(10);
 thrust::counting_iterator<int> last = first + 7;
 thrust::device_vector<int> d_data(7);

 int init_value = 1;
 my_op op(init_value);

 thrust::transform(first, last, d_data.begin(), op);
 for (int el = 0; el < 7; el++) {
    int dat = d_data[el];
    std::cout << dat  << " ";    }

 std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t13 t13.cu
$ ./t13
20 22 24 26 28 30 32
$
```

You may want to read the [thrust quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) to learn about thrust algorithm dispatch.